# How to start OpenTSDB?

Tags: java, hbase, opentsdb

I'm following the [getting started instructions](http://opentsdb.net/getting-started.htm) for OpenTSDB, but I get the below-shown errors when running the program. Can anyone help?

When running command:

```
./build/tsdb tsd --port=4242 --staticroot=build/staticroot --cachedir="$tsdtemp"
```

I get this error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1078) ~[zookeeper-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1-942149]
2011-12-19 10:07:54,459 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-12-19 10:07:54,461 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1078) ~[zookeeper-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1-942149]
^[[A2011-12-19 10:07:56,521 INFO  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181
2011-12-19 10:07:56,522 WARN  [main-SendThread(localhost:2181)] ClientCnxn: Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592) ~[na:1.6.0_20]
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1078) ~[zookeeper-3.3.1.jar:3.3.1-942149]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your zookeeper is down/not configured on poort 2181

you can start by checking the zoo.cfg file where you installed zookeepr

Comment: Thanks. yes my zookeper was down.